# HP-UX merging two volume group

Tags: backup-restoration, hp-ux

I have a system with 3 volume group (vg00, vg01 and vgdata).

I need to make a bootable tape, so I used the command below ad backup completed successfully.

```
make_tape_recovery -a /dev/rmt/0mn -x inc=vg00 -x inc=vg01
```

(this is not the exact syntax of `-x inc=vg00` but that is not the problem).

Now, I would like to know, when booting on the tape, will it give me one vg (vg00) or two vg (vg00+vg01) ?

I suppose there is enough disk space to hold the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignite software will gather all system configuration information, not only the specified files. This information includes LVM configuration, VG's and physical disks, so during recovery, it will try to restore the system configuration as much as it can. If the disks remain in the system, the original VG will be created.

I suppose you know the exact syntax:

# make_tape_recovery -a /dev/rmt/0mn -x inc_entire=vg00 -x inc_entire=vg01

Answer (score 1):

If the disks belonging to vg01 are present (attached to the server), the Ignite recovery will deliver your vg01 VG

If you are restoring the OS to another h/w, vg01 may need to be brought back. Move away /etc/lvmtab (mv /etc/lvmtab /etc/lvmtab.a), run /sbin/vgscan -av, /sbin/vgchange -a y vg01. You are done